# Getting old updates for minecraft xbox edition

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there a way to get old updates on minecraft Xbox edition? I want to be able to play the minecraft xbox version of beta 1.6.6 for a non-laggy nostalgia rush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no.  Your only options are:

- Whatever version shipped on the disc (assuming you bought a disc-based copy, delete the title updates from your system and then skip any updates)
- Whatever version you have now (assuming you haven't updated to the latest and you decline all future updates)
- Whatever version is the latest

There's no version history when it comes to Xbox Live patching of games, Minecraft included.

Comment: wait, what does deleting all the title updates except for the wanted one do?

Comment: @user3487713, there's just one "title update" file on the Xbox 360 hard drive.  Deleting it will revert you to the version on the disc.  There's not a list of updates that you can pick and choose from.

Comment: okay, maybe I could buy my friends disk copy...

Answer (score 0):

To all the people who are saying you can't, well you can. Go to xboxunity.com and go download the Minecraft title updates starting from 1. if you want to play later versions you have to download each update and launch Minecraft in that tu at least once before downloading later updates. Download horizon from wemod and grab a flash drive. Plug the flash drive into your Xbox 360 and format it, (if you skip this step horizon will not recognize you're flash drive.). Put it into your pc and inject the tu file you downloaded from Xbox unity into the folder that says title update. lastly, launch Minecraft using the flash drive and boom! Minecraft tu1 - tu11

Answer (score -1):

yes if you bought the game when it came out on xbox marketplace delete the update

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Yes, it actually does answer the question. He's saying to delete the update. He's not actually saying *how*, he's just saying you can.

Comment: @Rapitor wrong. He's trying to answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is a list of title updates for Minecraft. Here is a link to a download page for all of the updates:

http://digiex.net/downloads/download-center-2-0/xbox-360-content/title-updates/14121-minecraft-xbox-360-title-update-collection-download-title-update-31-a.html

You can just download the update you want and then add it onto a flash drive that's configured for xbox 360 using horizon.

Also, if you want a list of what every update added, I will leave a link right here:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Console_Edition_version_history